# How can I filter a Dynamic Distribution Group by Database name?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, restore

I need to create a dynamic DL to list the members of an individual database and I'm unable to get the powershell command to filter the results properly.

```
[PS] C:\>New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "test1233" 
    -RecipientFilter {Database -eq  "CN=JournalRecover,CN=Databases,
      CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,
      CN=Company,CN=MicrosoftExchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=com" }
```

The reason I'm attempting this DG is so that I can populate the following powershell script to export email for all users in a database

```
[PS] C:\>$mbxs = Get-MailboxDatabase rdb16 | Get-MailboxStatistics
[PS] C:\>New-MailboxSearch -Name "test2" -SourceMailboxes $mbxs 
         -TargetMailbox journalrecover  -StartDate "11/1/2012"
         -EndDate "11/15/2012" -IncludeUnsearchableItems:$true 
         -SearchDumpster:$true -ExcludeDuplicateMessages:$true
         -DoNotIncludeArchive:$true
```

**Question**

1. How can I create a DG that filters by Database?
2. OR how can I alter the mailbox search so it applies to multiple mailboxes in the database?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error when issuing the `New-DynamicDistributionGroup` cmdlet? if so, please post it

Comment: I don't get any error, I simply get no results when expanding the group, even though normal mailbox users have a account on journalrecover

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct but you have a typo in your DN. `CN=MicrosoftExchange` should be `CN=Microsoft Exchange`. You can also preview membership with:

> $dyn = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup test1233
>   Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $dyn.RecipientFilter